# Oblique Decision Tree HHCART algorithm explaination

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees

I am now studying a paper about implementing oblique decision tree algorithm

https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.03415

I was wondering if any code implementation and alternative explaination, as a support material to the paper, is available for the HHCART algorithm method.

Thanks a lot